# "ProductName is not a valid short name" when installing program

Tags: windows-services, setup-project

I have a Windows service that is package into an MSI via Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project. This has worked well for years, and we typically installed this service on a Windows Server 2003 machine. Now we're upgrading to a Windows Server 2012 machine and getting an error message when installing this program:

> 'QuickReportsEmailerService' is not a valid short file name.

This prevents the program from being installed. I tried changing the ProductName in my setup project to QREmailerService but then the error message just changes to:

> 'QREmailerService' is not a valid short file name.

I executed my installer with the /lv options and I get this output:

> The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this
>   package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code
>   is 2835. The arguments are: ErrorIcon, ErrorDialog,  MSI (c) (68:F0)
>   [14:34:41:379]: Product: QREmailerService -- Error 1325.
>   'QREmailerService' is not a valid short file name.
>
> Action ended 14:34:41: CostFinalize. Return value 3. MSI (c) (68:F0)
>   [14:34:41:379]: Doing action: FatalErrorForm Action start 14:34:41:
>   FatalErrorForm. MSI (c) (68:F0) [14:34:41:379]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3:
>   ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL,
>   `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'FatalErrorForm'

What do I need to change in order to get this installed?

Some more info:

- I'm an administrator on the server
- I saw some [similar errors](https://superuser.com/questions/258239/error-1325-username-is-not-a-valid-short-file-name) when I Googled this, but they all suggested I modify this registry key. But I checked what they were changing it to, my registry key was already in that format.

Edit-
I fixed the problem by changing the ProductName to "QR". But that's hardly acceptable, now it's not descriptive enough. Why is it getting mad? Is there some maximum length of a ProductName I should know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

So my setup project had the application folder default to: D:[ProductName]

But our new 2012 server doesn't have a D drive, I want to install on E drive. So I changed that in the setup project to be C:[ProductName]. C drive exists, so now in the installer UI I just have to manually change to E drive.

Not sure why it worked with D:[ProductName] when the ProductName was just "QR" but oh well.

Comment: It must be because [ProductName] ends up in the Directory table of the MSI file, DefaultDir, and when it gets resolved it's not actually in the correct format of shortfilename!longfilename.